# Using operations in asymptotics

Tags: solution-verification, asymptotics

I know that: $$\pi(x)\sim\frac{x}{\log x}$$Solving for $\log x$ (if it is allowed):$$\log x\sim\frac{x}{\pi(x)}$$I also know that $$\pi(x)\sim\text{li}(x)$$So substituting it back into the second relation: $$\log x\sim\frac{x}{\text{li}(x)}$$But when I graph this it doesn't seem like this is true. Is my use of operations in the asymptotics relations correct? Are there concrete rules for how to use operations with asymptotics? I couldn't find anything with a google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that asymptotic equivalence works like equality in relation to basic operations can be dangerous business. To be safe, you should write out the definition of the relation $\sim$ in the context of the PNT:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)} = 1
$$
and analogously for the relationship with the logarithmic integral. The limit is capable of messing up naive manipulations: for example, you cannot derive from here that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} |\pi(x) - \frac{x}{\log x}| = 0
$$
as we already know this is false. You can also safely get around working under limits by working with equalities with error bounds, such as various well-known expressions of the form
$$
\pi(x) = \operatorname{Li}(x) + \mathcal{O}(f(x)).
$$
Again, at the end of the day you'll want to expand out the big-O notation to make sure you're performing valid operations: this "equality" is technically an inequality, so you'll want to be careful with multiplications and divisions involving negative signs or other inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{x}{\log(x)}$ is only a rough estimate for $\pi(x)$ , in particular for small numbers. Hence the last asymptotic cannot be visualized either since it is basically equivalent to it.

Comment: But is the last relation true and it just sucks?

Comment: Asymptotically, it is true as you demonstrated.